# Firestore Security rule always returns null for resource

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to create some firestore security rules. However, every rule that I write that involves something other than the users database pulling the document of the current user results in an error. There is some difference I am missing.

Here is the query and the data. The resource object is always null. Any get function that involves pulling from the design database using the designId variable also results in null.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't tell from your screenshots which document you're trying to get in the simulator. Maybe it doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought that the simulator test the rules? As long as there are docs in the collection, wouldn't they be a resource?

Comment: The simulator prompts you to indicate what kind of operation to perform (read or write) that would trigger a rule.  You have to say which document to work with.  The screenshot you have here doesn't show that operation - you've scrolled down so that we can't see it.

Comment: Ahhh. I have tried /designs/{design=**} and /designs/{design} and other things.

Comment: I understand, but **we can't see which document you're trying to read**.  Your screenshot simply does not show it.  You've scrolled down away from the part that shows the places where you type it in.  Without seeing that, we don't know if you're actually trying to work with a document that exists.  We should be able to see the form fields where you choose "Simulation type" and "Location"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're putting a pattern into the form, which is not valid.  You need to provide the specific document that you want to simulate a read or write.  This means you need to copy the ID of the document into that field.  It should be something like "/designs/j8R...Lkh", except you provide the actual value.

Comment: I entered an ID and it worked. Perhaps I was mistaken as to the purpose of the simulator.